# Taking snapshot of the invisible region with Flutter Google Maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-packages

I am using the Google Maps package for showing flights on the map. Flights can be west and east, for example from Istanbul to San Francisco and Istanbul to Tokyo. This means I can not see everything on the mobile device screen even with maximum zoom-out. If I want to take a snapshot with the controller's takeSnapshot() method, it doesn't give the invisible region.

Is there any way to get a snapshot of the whole world?
Example snapshots of the current situation.

[image][image][image]

Comment: you can use the bounds for the LAT LNGS and use like this.
      controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(_bounds(markers), 50));

Comment: Already used this method and these were the result. Zoom out level is not enough to see whole path or markers.